# Justify css menu in IE

Tags: css, menu, justify

I want to make a CSS menu auto-justify full width.

HTML:

```
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">click</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">click</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">long clickclick</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">click</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">clickclickclick</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">click click 666</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0;
  font-size: 14px\9; /* IE6-9 hack */
  line-height: 0;
}
.menu:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}
.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.menu ul li a {
  line-height: 54px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MV7hb/)

It working good on Chrome/Firefox, but not working on IE 10-11. Coud someone please help me fix this?
[image: What I see: top is Chrome (good), bottom IE11 (bad)]

Comment: Doesn't work in chrome for me... or firefox...

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, add text-justify: distribute to your .menu and it will work fine.

Comment: My justify layouts were breaking for lists in IE11. This fixed - thanks!

Comment: Thanks, along with text-align: justify I added the text-justify: distribute;, it fixes me the issue, good thing is this text-justify: distribute; only supported only in IE, so no problem adding it

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to have the menu spread across the width of the page? In that case, adding `min-width:100%;` to `.menu` in your CSS file will achieve that.

Comment: @Vladimir - It's definitley working. Do you mean it's not going right to the edges? Because that's a matter of setting the padding and margins of the body, nothing to do with your .menu element.

Comment: I see this http://s019.radikal.ru/i608/1312/6f/cb10772b793c.png (top is Chrome - bottom is IE11)

Comment: Hi, @Vladimir - that's website's blocked for me. Can you upload to a more reputable site please?

Comment: Afraid I'm not sure what else to suggest - my solution works, so there must be something wrong elsewhere in your code.